# how to adjust the height of the subview according to its content which is embedded in the UIStackView

Tags: swift

I have embedded three views inside one stack view and in those three subviews, every view contains one text view, image view, one view for videos, one more view for pdfs and one more subview..I want to adjust the height of every subview (3 views )according to its content which is presented inside the stack view.

Comment: Can you add screenshot of your View hierarchy?